# Eclipse Mars Support for Java9 - Build path settings

Tags: java, eclipse, java-9

I tried to install and use the [Java 9 support for Eclipse Mars](http://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2015/june/article4.php). However when trying to compile a simple Hello World program I get two errors in Eclipse:

1. > The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files    Main.java /Java9Test/src  line 
   >   1   Java Problem
2. > The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for java.lang.Object. Fix
   >   the build path    then try building this
   >   project Java9Test       Unknown Java Problem

   (although I cannot see
   any errors when looking at the build path)

Is anyone facing similiar problems? How can this be fixed?

**Here is what I've done so far ...**

1. Installing OpenJDK 9 went fine (javac and java are working
   properly).
2. Eclipse update went fine (I did it using the Marketplace and using the provided link).
3. When starting eclipse using Java 9, I got two errors (one regarding the Java version, and one regarding a garbage collector
   option) but managed to "fix" them by removing these options from
   eclipse.ini.
4. Configured the OpenJDK 9 in Eclipse, changed the source level to 9 and rebuilt the project/restarted Eclipse a couple of times.

Comment: Which version of Java 9 are you running eclipse with? There were changes to the Jimage modules since b74 onward.

Comment: I am using 1.9.0-ea-b76 ....

Comment: @chuchichaeschtli Did you ever get this working?

Comment: @James_D: No but it is on my todo list. I will update the post if I get it working.

Comment: The version of eclipse you mentioned is fairly old. The JDK's JRT implementation went through significant changes over time. They first had jimgae then replaced them with jmod files. Eclipse also had to change accordingly. So, it is possible that the eclipse doesn't work well with the JDK you have. Just take the latest of both, things should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

***Update:16 October,2017***

The message is clear from the Eclipse maintainers **::**

> [Mars](https://projects.eclipse.org/releases/mars) is a past version of Eclipse. Please visit our download page
>   for the latest version of Eclipse.

You shall upgrade to using ***[Eclipse Oxygen.1a (4.7.1a) Release](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/)*** released on October 11, 2017 to support JPMS.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse Mars does not support Java 9. It'll throw IllegalStateException. It'll support till Java 8.