# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.sql.Date in a eclipse mars based application with Java9 runtime

Tags: java, osgi, java-9

I like to test if our RCP Application is running on a Java 9 runtime.

I already updated my eclipse **Mars** based RCP application to the latest Mars release to get it running from the osgi point of view.

Now I get a new exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.sql.Date
at org.apache.axis.encoding.DefaultTypeMappingImpl.class$(DefaultTypeMappingImpl.java:120)
at org.apache.axis.encoding.DefaultTypeMappingImpl.initMappings(DefaultTypeMappingImpl.java:206)
at org.apache.axis.encoding.DefaultTypeMappingImpl.<init>(DefaultTypeMappingImpl.java:91)
at org.apache.axis.encoding.DefaultTypeMappingImpl.getSingletonDelegate(DefaultTypeMappingImpl.java:85)
at org.apache.axis.encoding.TypeMappingRegistryImpl.<init>(TypeMappingRegistryImpl.java:155)
at org.apache.axis.encoding.TypeMappingRegistryImpl.<init>(TypeMappingRegistryImpl.java:149)
at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployment.<init>(WSDDDeployment.java:449)
at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDocument.setDocument(WSDDDocument.java:139)
at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDocument.<init>(WSDDDocument.java:65)
at org.apache.axis.configuration.FileProvider.configureEngine(FileProvider.java:179)
at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.init(AxisEngine.java:172)
at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.<init>(AxisEngine.java:156)
at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.<init>(AxisClient.java:52)
at org.apache.axis.client.Service.getAxisClient(Service.java:104)
at org.apache.axis.client.Service.<init>(Service.java:113)
...
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:558)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.WorkbenchServiceRegistry.getSourceProviders(WorkbenchServiceRegistry.java:177)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.SourceProviderService.readRegistry(SourceProviderService.java:108)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$47.runWithException(Workbench.java:2416)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:32)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4155)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3772)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2989)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$9(Workbench.java:2894)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:685)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:606)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at de.softproject.x4frontend.standalone.Application.start(Application.java:24)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1488)
```

I also added the **--add-modules=java.se** option to the vm arguments. But there is no difference if I start with or without this option.

The source and compile target is 1.8 I just like to check if it is running on a JRE 9.

I'm clueless now what I'm missing. Maybe someone has a hint what I can try next? Maybe osgi is not recognizing the module as bundle?

Comment: @Sorontur Could probably be a bug in Mars? Seems a [past version anyway](https://www.eclipse.org/mars/)

Comment: Is it possible that Apache Axis has been loaded by a custom class loader that delegates directly to the boot class loader? That would explain the issue. There is no guarantee that all platform classes are visible to the boot loader.

Comment: @Sorontur Can you report this to https://bugs.eclipse.org?

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov: I did: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=526922

Answer (score 1):

To make it better visible i sum up the result of the bug ticket:

Mars is not able to access the java.* modules and it will not be fixed. Oxygen 1a is the first platform version which works.

I made a minimum example with the exception result above and it works in the Oxygen platform.

So basically every RCP application needs an upgrade to Oxygen if a safe run in java 9 is required.

A bit sad that java 9 is not really backwards compatible like the other major verisons. But lets hope that this is well invested :)

Comment: Browsed further, and found I made [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46766823/1746118) to a similar thread a month back.